# add xml:base to xml file in java

Tags: java, xml, jena

I want to add an xml:base declaration to an xml file in java.  I currently have the xml output in an OutputStream that was generated by some third party code.

The file starts out like this:

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns="http://www.mycompany.com/myNS#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns="http://www.mycompany.com/myNS#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xml:base="http://www.mycompany.com/myNS">
```

I must be having a brain fart or something, because I can't think of a good way to do this pragmatically.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The ByteArrayInputStream won't scale for large files, and I didn't like the idea of using a temp file.  I also thought it was overkill to load the whole file into the DOM just to add the `xml:base` tag.

Here's an alternate solution using pipes and a simple hand rolled parsing code to add the tag.

```
PipedInputStream pipedInput = new PipedInputStream();
PipedOutputStream pipedOutput = new PipedOutputStream(pipedInput);
new Thread(new ModelExportThread(model, pipedOutput)).start();
int bufferSize = 1024;
byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];            
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
int bytesRead = pipedInput.read(bytes, 0, bufferSize);
boolean done = false;
String startRDF = "<rdf:RDF";
while (bytesRead > 0) {
    if (!done) {
        stringBuffer.append(new String(bytes, 0, bytesRead));
        int startIndex = stringBuffer.indexOf(startRDF);
        if ((startIndex >= 0)) {
            stringBuffer.insert(startIndex + startRDF.length(), " xml:base=\"" + namespace + "\"");
            outputStream.write(stringBuffer.toString().getBytes());
            stringBuffer.setLength(0);
            done = true;
        }
    } else {
        outputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    bytesRead = pipedInput.read(bytes, 0, bufferSize);
}
outputStream.flush();
```

Here's the threaded code to write to the output pipe.

```
public class ModelExportThread implements Runnable {

    private final OntModel model;
    private final OutputStream outputStream;

    public ModelExportThread(OntModel model, OutputStream outputStream) {
        this.model = model;
        this.outputStream = outputStream;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            model.write(outputStream, "RDF/XML-ABBREV");
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(OntologyModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `xml:base` used in RDF/XML serialization by obtaining the appropriate RDFWriter and setting its `xmlbase` property to your chosen `xmlbase`.  The following code reads a model from a string (the important part of this question is about how to write the model, not where it comes frm) and then writes it in RDF/XML twice, each time with a different `xml:base`.

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.RDFWriter;

public class ChangeBase {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final String NS = "http://example.org/";
        final String text = "" +
                "@prefix ex: <"+NS+">.\n" +
                "ex:foo a ex:Foo .\n" +
                "ex:foo ex:frob ex:bar.\n"; 
        final Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        try ( final InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream( text.getBytes() )) {
            model.read( in, null, "TTL" );
        }
        // get a writer for RDF/XML-ABBREV, set its xmlbase to the NS, and write the model
        RDFWriter writer = model.getWriter( "RDF/XML-ABBREV" );
        writer.setProperty( "xmlbase", NS );
        writer.write( model, System.out, null );

        // change the base to example.com (.com, not .org) and write again
        writer.setProperty( "xmlbase", "http://example.com" );
        writer.write( model, System.out, null );
    }
}
```

The output is (notice that in the first case, the base is `htttp://example.org/` and in the second, it's `http://example.com` (the difference is .org vs. .com):

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:ex="http://example.org/"
  xml:base="http://example.org/">
  <ex:Foo rdf:about="foo">
    <ex:frob rdf:resource="bar"/>
  </ex:Foo>
</rdf:RDF>
```

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:ex="http://example.org/"
  xml:base="http://example.com">
  <ex:Foo rdf:about="http://example.org/foo">
    <ex:frob rdf:resource="http://example.org/bar"/>
  </ex:Foo>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Answer (score -1):

After some digging, this is what I did.

NOTE: I had the third party app write the xml to a StringWriter instead of an output stream named 'writer'.  'outputStream' is the name of the stream the resulting XML will be written to.

```
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(writer.toString().getBytes());
Document myXML = 
     DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputStream);
myXML.getDocumentElement().setAttribute("xml:base", namespace);
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(outputStream);
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(myXML);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

I really thought this would be easier.

Comment: This is shorter than the other answer that you posted, but it's even easier than this.  Once you've read the model, you just set the `xmlbase` property of a writer and use the writer to write the model.  I've added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18987916/1281433) showing this.